# How to make installed geoserver 2.18 as windows service?

Tags: service, geoserver, reinstall

How to make installed geoserver 2.18 as windows service?  Two yeas ago I have install it on windows server 2008 R2 and sometimes it stops (when my session closed, for example), which is not acceptable,  it needs geoserver  works all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Install tomcat as a windows service and deploy the geoserver war to tomcat. Note you will generally get better performance on a Linux box.

Comment: This is a new question for me, I'll look into it. The question is - what is used instead of Tomcat servlets now in 2.18 version? Is it possible to simply install, say, the version of the Geoserver 2.21 and save the settings of the layers published now? How to redirect geoserver to tomcat?

Comment: GeoServer is installed in tomcat - you add the war file to the webapps folder

Comment: It looks like I have Jetty installed (https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/installation/win_binary.html ). How to upgrade geoserver from v.2.18 with jetty to 2.21 with Tomcat and save exported layer settings

Comment: have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/index.html#installation)?

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw some upgrade discussions and wanted confirmation that the data is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Geoserver installation folder there is a folder called wrapper. This has a Java Service Launcher jsl.exe, renamed as GeoServer.exe

https://www.roeschter.de/index.html

This launcher exe needs a .ini file (exists right there) that contains the configuration for the windows service.
Just edit this file if you want to have custom data directory, custom service name, display name, description and you're good to go.